# Is there a way to for a VSCode snippet extension to identify already written text, so it doesn't duplicate it?

Tags: autocomplete, duplicates, vscode-extensions, vscode-snippets

For example, suppose you have a snippet that writes this whole `System.out.println()` starting from where your cursor is, and you have written the following:

```
int num = 10;
.println(num);
```

Let's say your cursor is right at the left of the dot from the print statement, and now you want to use the snippet to auto complete the whole command. Is it possible to make it so that the already written `.println(num)` is identified, and the snippet will just write the remaining `System.out`

A better example is if I want to autocomplete `string with parameters ""` in the line:

```
check that page contains ""
```

where my cursor is on the left of the double quotes. I want it to not duplicate the `""`, and just write `string with parameters`. That way, it would be `check that page contains string with parameters ""` and not `check that page contains string with parameters """"`.

Comment: I don't think there is any built-in way to do that, other than only inserting `System` and use intellisense to work your way to `.println()`.  On a case-by-case basis I think this could be done with an extension but it would be unique for each snippet, there being no general setting in vscode to achieve what you want.  I could probably make a keybinding to trigger an extension I have written to accomplish this if you care for a one-off demo.

Comment: @Mark I updated this question with an example that explains it better. I am writing an extension as well, so I don't think I need any settings alone.

Comment: And the `string with parameters` would go into the quotes?

Comment: @Mark it would go right before the quotes, checkout the edited question.